# I'm trying to track all files except a certain type in git LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

I want to use git LFS for all file types except ".m" files. I've written this in .gitattributes:

```
# Track everything
* filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

#Except
.gitignore -filter=lfs -diff=lfs -merge=lfs -text
.gitattributes -filter=lfs -diff=lfs -merge=lfs -text
*.m -filter=lfs -diff=lfs -merge=lfs -text
```

This results in ".m" files being tracked. Where is my mistake?

Note that apart from .gitignore and .gitattributes, everything else is in folders and subfolders.

Thank you

Comment: The `filter=lfs` is the crucial part that tells Git to run the files through Git-LFS to cause them to be stored outside the repository. But `-filter=lfs` is not the right way to clear it: `!filter` is the way to clear it. It's probably wise to clear the remaining settings: `*.m !filter !diff !merge -text`, for instance, if you want to keep them set to `-text`.

Comment: @torek nope. Negative paths are forbidden: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#Documentation/gitattributes.txt-Unspecified

Comment: @VonC: not a negative path, a "clear the setting". `*.m` is a positive path; `!filter` says "when we match this file, unset `filter`".

Comment: @torek OK, I will have to test it then. I though `filter=` (empty value) would have worked better.

Comment: @VonC: Not having Git-LFS installed and configured I can't test it for sure, but `filter=` would certainly override the Git-LFS filtering. :-) Git doesn't seem to mind an empty setting for these attributes, so this should work too. For any attributes where unset differs from set-to-empty, though, the `!` method would matter.

Comment: @torek I've tried your solution but it didn't stop tracking the .m files. Considering I'm brand new to git I'll be as clear as possible: .m files were being tracked, .gitattributes and .gitignore files werent. I've changed gitattributes using the ! syntax you gave me, commited, and then checked which files were still LFS tracked, and that still includes .m files.

Do I need to actively untrack them? Would starting a new repo work?

Comment: I don't actually *use* Git-LFS, so beyond what the `.gitattributes` directives are doing, I can't really help any further. How Git-LFS decides that some file is "lfs-tracked", I don't know.

Comment: I've started a new repo using the syntax you've provided and it worked. Thanks!